# How can I open a new window and pass to it (for the later purpose of printing them) only selected html elements with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, printing, element

If my code looks like this:

```
<table>

<td class="noprint">1</td>
<td class="noprint">2</td>
<td class="print">3</td>
<td class="noprint">4</td>
<td class="noprint">5</td>
<td class="print">6</td>
<td class="noprint">7</td>
<td class="noprint">8</td>
<td class="print">9</td>

</table>
```

And I would like to open a new window with javascript to print only elements with a class="print", how do I do that? Tnx.

Comment: print as to print on a paper or print as to display on a page? You want to open a new window and "pass" elements with class "print" to that page?

Comment: exactly like second thing you said: "open a new window and "pass" elements with class "print" to that page"

Comment: @RobiNetko: So the new window would be blank to start with, and you'd add only this table with only the `class="print"` elements to the page?

Comment: exactly that, that would be perfect if possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've said in a comment that you want to:

> "open a new window and "pass" elements with class "print" to that page"

You can clone your table, remove any cells that aren't `class="print"`, get the HTML for that, and write it out to the new window:

```
var clone = document.querySelector("selector for your table").cloneNode(true);
var list = clone.querySelectorAll("td:not(.print)");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) { // QSA returns static lists, so we can loop normally
    list[i].parentNode.removeChild(list[i]);
}
var wnd = window.open();
wnd.document.write("<!doctype html><html><title>Something Appropriate</title></head><body></body></html>");
wnd.document.close();
wnd.document.body.innerHTML = clone.outerHTML
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/nipifi/1)

But note that most of the time, this isn't necessary. If your main window has `@media screen` and `@media print` rules, you can manage what's shown vs. what's printed right there in the main window, without having to open a new one.

Example - CSS:

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
td {
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
@media screen {
  .print-only {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media print {
  .screen-only {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td class="screen-only">Screen Only</td>
    <td class="print-only">Print Only</td>
    <td>Either print or screen</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/nipifi/2)

Note that when you're viewing the page on-screen, you see "Screen Only" and "Either print or screen" cells, but when you print (or view a print preview), you see "Print Only" and "Either print or screen" cells.

It's very powerful, and doesn't require any script.

Comment: @RobiNetko: I've *just* updated it now that I understand your question better.

Comment: @RobiNetko: No worries. :-) I've also added a CSS-only option. Best,

Answer (score -1):

You need to make a css and give media = "print", something like this:

```
<link rel="your path" media="print">
/* define these properties into css file: */
.noprint{display: none;}
.print{display: block;}
```

It will work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here, we don't open with a salutation, and we don't close with a signature or "thanks" or anything. Also, don't mark up your answer as code (which is what you've done by indenting it four spaces). The text of your answer should be normal text. To mark up blocks of code, use the `{}` button. To mark something up inline , use backticks. I've fixed it for you on this occasion.

Comment: Note that you **don't** want to give `td` elements `display: block`.